# Publishing ASP.NET vNext with Web Deploy?

Tags: asp.net, iis, microsoft-web-deploy

I've scoured the web for an answer or hints but does anyone have any information on how to deploy an ASP.NET vNext application to a traditional (i.e. regular, not Azure) server using Web Deploy?  I had no trouble deploying via the File System method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first install Web Deploy on the IIS Server. Check this link for more info: [Installing and Configuring Web Deploy on IIS 8.0 or Later](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later)

On a different note ASP.NET vNext is still in beta so even if you try to deploy, it won't run there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  I finally got it to work.  The last piece of the puzzle for me was to Enable 32-Bit Applications in my application pool.